# How can I install the Beautiful Soup module on the window 7?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I found the post at http://ricardianambivalence.com/2011/08/14/beautifulsoup-in-python-with-windows-7/

(I used python 2.6 and downloaded beautifulsoup4-4.1.3)

I could not find "BeautifulSoup.pyc" after run "setup.py"

Any suggest?

Comment: Did you look at the output of `setup.py`? Did it succeed? Can you import BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I just double click at that file and cmd pop up and gone...just that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's in no way a good method, but what I always do is copying the folder`bs4` at path `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`. Always works :)

Comment: I did like you said copy folder "bs4" to C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages I tested by typing from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup It's an error said "No module named BeautifulSoup"

Comment: You should write `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. The one you've written will work for the old `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 5):

To check whether your installation is successful, type in a Python shell (or any of your Python script):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

To install a pure python package such as `beautifulsoup4`, run:

```
C:\> pip install beautifulsoup4
```

To install `pip`, download [`get-pip.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and run:

```
C:\> python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Copy and paste as said in second comment as test by typing "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" It seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Open cmd.

Go to the directory where you decompressed the package, then write this:

```
c:\python33\python.exe setup.py install
```

Change python33 to the directory where python is installed.

Comment: Please use the markup to format your answers, they are a lot easier to read this way